# Create new lines in a database based on a condition

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an issue for which I cannot seem to find an answer (I am new to this and clearly I do not know how to create an append query properly...)

I have a table "Basket" in which I create new lines each week on a form.
Each time I create a new "basket", I want my "follow basket" table to be incremented with a new line, attached for each customer following the proper conditions (of my table "customers").

So I need a query (i think) that copy the data from "basket" in the "follow basket" for each "customer" where its conditions match the "basket"'s.
Do you see what I mean ?

Example :
I create basket "Type P" for week S1
It creates week S1 basket in "follow basket" for each customer who subscribed for basket "Type P".
In "follow basket" I can then say if they had their basket delivered and paid.

Thank you for your help...

Here is my database structure as asked

[image]

Panier : basket
suivi_paiement_panier : follow basket
Particuliers : customers

```
I also have a "semainier" field (weeks) because we create specific baskets each week and all the follow up is made like that (S1, S2, ... = Week1, week2...)
```

Comment: If this is purely a ms-access question please remove the mysql tag.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a 'batch creation' of records. Are you using autonumber PK for basket record? So the trick with 'batch creation' is to first commit new basket record and grab the newly created PK for use in append query creating records in "follow basket" table. Edit question to show table structures.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do ! But it is a bit trickier because I have another database in the middle, the "semainier" one... And that none of the append queries I tried so far worked...

Comment: Yes, need to create other records first so can get the "semainier" key for use in junction table with customers. Adjust the SQL suggested in my answer.

Comment: I just noticed a problem. Type_de_panier is a multi-value field. For suggested query to work, need a single value text field in Particuliers. Cannot use Type_Panier field from Paniers. Fields to filter on must be in Particuliers table.

Comment: I figured out a way to make multi-value field work. Revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'batch create' a set of new records based on new data as well as existing data. An INSERT SELECT SQL statement is commonly used to accomplish that.

Multi-value field Type_de_panier complicates but it is manageable.

Another complication is referencing form controls to pull criteria parameters because likely form/subform arrangement is involved in data entry and parameters are sourced from different forms. If you have Samainier as main (parent) form and Panier as subform and code is behind Panier form, consider:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) " & _
    "SELECT " & Me.Parent!Semainier_IDDate & " AS SID, IDT1 FROM Particuliers " & _
    "WHERE Fréquence='" & Me.Parent!Paire_Impaire & "' AND Actif=True " & _
    "AND IDT1 IN " & _
        "(SELECT IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_de_panier.Value='" & Me!Type_Panier & "')"
```

Make adjustments if your form arrangement is different.

Now have to figure out what event to put code into. If you want to rely on user to initiate this action, then use a button Click.

Comment: I actually have more conditions than that in other tables too... how do i do it ? frequency in "semainier" (paire / impaire) that is in my customers as well, and i want also to create the batch only for "active" customers. So i have 3 parameters. Frequency, basket, active. Frequency in "semainier", basket in "paniers" and only the active customers.

Comment: I'm really sorry i don't understand any of the statements so i'm not sure I do as I'm supposed to. I don't see what to put in "ID" and "AS BID"... Private Sub Command20_Click()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) SELECT " & Me!ID & " AS BID, " _
    "IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_Panier='" & Me!Type_Panier & "'"
End Sub

Comment: Me!ID would be IDDate value from form. Assumes code is behind Semainier form. Can add more WHERE criteria for active customers, again, don't know field name: `AND Active=True`.

Comment: DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) SELECT " & Me!IDDate & " AS BID, " _
    "IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_Panier='" & Me!Type_Panier & "' AND Fréquence='" & Me!Paire_Impaire & "' AND Actif=True"                                                               what is "AS BID" ? and it says "expected end of statement" so i suppose I have not enough "" and the end of "AS BID" (what does it mean ?) with the underscore _ is not working in the code. I'm such a newbie i'm sorry ..

Comment: Underscore is line continuation character. SQL code is typed on two lines. I missed a & character in front of the underscore. Corrected. 'BID` is just an alias field name, use whatever you want.

Comment: `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) SELECT " & Me!IDDate & " Date, " & _
    "IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_Panier='" & Me!Type_Panier & "' AND Fréquence='" & Me!Paire_Impaire & "' AND Actif=True"`

Comment: What field type is IDDate? If it is a date/time then must use # delimiters if you reference a textbox or field: `SELECT #" & Me!IDDate & "# AS DT,`. If you just want the current date then: `SELECT Date() AS DT, `

Comment: IDDate is an autonumber in semainier. It's not working, I'm way over my head >_<       `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) SELECT " & Me!Semainier_IDDate & _
    "IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_Panier='" & Me!Type_Panier & "' AND Fréquence='" & Me!Paire_Impaire & "' AND Actif=True"`

Comment: Then why did you use Date? Date is a function (a reserved word). Don't use reserved words as names. You are missing alias field name and comma.  `SELECT " & Me!Semainier_IDDate & " AS SID, " &`. Assuming Type_Panier and Frequence are text fields, which need the apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: What is the alias field name ? That's the thing, i do not know what to put there. Should I put IDDate then ?

Comment: I have this (no error on the code it says)` CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Suivi_paiement_paniers(IDDate, IDT1) SELECT " & Me!Semainier_IDDate & " AS SID,  & IDT1 FROM Particuliers WHERE Type_Panier='" & Me!Type_Panier & "' AND Fréquence='" & Me!Paire_Impaire & "' AND Actif=True" `

Comment: Look at my example in answer again. There is no & in `AS SID, IDT1`. Also, added info about using multi-value field and referencing form and subform. Alias field name is not a field in table. Just use the one I made up.

Comment: So, the button is actually is the parent form (so I deleted "parent" because the expression wouldn't stand it) and ran the code again. Issue with the "Fréquence" thing, saying it cannot be used as a WHERE or HAVING clause, due to my multi valued thingy I think... Had this issue already on other forms and had to create a form for each, not the best. I suppose it would do the same on Type_Panier because it is a multi valued field to...

Comment: Type_Panier is not a multi-value field - Type_de_panier is multi-value field and I show how to handle. Can't even see any Fréquence field(s) in the relationships image but I expect same technique could be used. Now if you are using a form/subform arrangement with code behind main form, then referencing field/control on subform would be like: `Me.SubformContainerName!Type_Panier`.

Comment: So... I'm back. Type_de_panier is a multi value field also, because you can't have a choice when you create one. I tried it again and again, in the main form and the subform S_Paniersemaine and I can't make it work. My main form contains the tables "Semainier" and "Paniers". The subform contains the table "Détail paniers" (which is linked to the list of products). Says it can't find "Type_Panier" in my expression. This is making me crazy

Comment: And finally, I tried again, in the subform. At least it doesn't say anything anymore, but nothing happens...

Comment: SO is not intended to be a discussion forum. I provided an example appropriate to your situation. If you still can't get it to work, probably need to use a forum that facilitates attaching files so you can provide yours for analysis.

Comment: alright... i'll try that then. Thanks for all the help :)